# HTML Email Signature Image not displaying in correct position

Tags: html, email-signature

I am new to HTML and created an email signature for the first time. The HTML signature displays perfectly in the browser but when I paste the signature into my Gmail or my email client the images seem to move around. I have tried to look for answers on how to fix this problem but with my lack of experience, it is hard to understand what I have done wrong.

Would anyone please be able to advise me where my mistake is?

Email signature in browser
[Browser display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g8cW.png)

VS

Email signature in Gmail
[Gmail display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL26m.png)

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>MF - Email signature</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (MF - Email signature.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="550" height="127" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <a href="https://uboomi.co.za"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0YYMMKv/MF-Email-signature-02.gif" width="115" height="127" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kgNJvrWJ/MF-Email-signature-03.gif" width="151" height="39" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hsysj8x7/MF-Email-signature-04.png" width="393" height="101" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="mailto:michelle@uboomi.co.za"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XY6N5NG1/MF-Email-signature-05.gif" width="151" height="20" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="tel:+2782769369"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Y0JrbMX9/MF-Email-signature-06.gif" width="151" height="19" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://uboomi.co.za"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vT18rctk/MF-Email-signature-07.gif" width="151" height="23" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/RC8ZMLMB/MF-Email-signature-08.gif" width="544" height="26" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to use only the  tag as signature and not the whole `<html>`-, `<head>`-, `<body>`-tags. Maybe that will help already...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried that and it looks a bit better but it still does not align correctly in Gmail.